# PHP Postgres: Get Last Insert ID

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, sequence, last-insert-id

I found a couple of other questions on this topic.  This one...

[mysql_insert_id alternative for postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956/)

...and [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) seem to indicate that you can call `lastval()` any time and it will work as expected.  But this one...

[Postgresql and PHP: is the currval a efficent way to retrieve the last row inserted id, in a multiuser application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892200/)

...seems to state that it has to be within a transaction.  So my question is this: can I just wait as long as I like before querying for `lastval()` (without a transaction)?  And is that reliable in the face of many concurrent connections?

Comment: Sequences depends on session not on transaction. But it is not good to wait and execute other queries meanwhile, you may receive lastval of other query.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE in PostgreSQL have a RETURNING clause which means you can do:

```
INSERT INTO ....
RETURNING id;
```

Then the query will return the value it inserted for id for each row inserted. Saves a roundtrip to the server.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer! Exactly what I needed, halves the number of queries I need to make for certain operations.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, if needed, you can return multiple values - RETURNING * will return the entire inserted row.

Comment: What if you don't know the name of the id field?

Comment: @JoePrivett, in normal applications that is not very realistic. Do you have a concrete case? If yes it would be better to post your own question where you explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, [the sequence functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-sequence.html) provide **multiuser-safe** methods for obtaining successive sequence values from sequence objects.

Comment: I'm so glad to see that sequences are now ANSI -- AUTOINCREMENT/IDENTITY are too limiting.